# Django cannot delete single object after rewriting model.Manager method

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to rewrite get_by_natural_key method on django manager (models.Manager). After adding model (NexchangeModel) I can delete all() objects but single - cannot.

Can:

```
SmsToken.objects.all().delete()
```

Cannot:

```
SmsTokent.objects.last().delete()
```

Code:

```
from django.db import models
from core.common.models import SoftDeletableModel, TimeStampedModel, UniqueFieldMixin

class NexchangeManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, param):
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        lookup = {qs.model.NATURAL_KEY: param}
        return self.get(**lookup)


class NexchangeModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    objects = NexchangeManager()

class SmsToken(NexchangeModel, SoftDeletableModel, UniqueFieldMixin):
    sms_token = models.CharField(
        max_length=4, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sms_token')
    send_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: on all() I am getting delete message.: i.e:  (1, {'accounts.SmsToken': 1}). On last() nothing (None) but it should also give a similar message (pk of record which was just deleted).

Comment: `all()` returns a `QuerySet`, `last()` an instance. Therefore I wouldn't be that suprised by the different behaviour, as the first delete-function is the one of the Manager/QuerySet and the second the one of your model. Of course this doesn't explain why delete doesn't work ...

Comment: ... rereading your comment: Did you check that the instance isn't deleted?

Comment: yes.
This is probably some conflict with SoftDeletableModel because it is also creates a manager called active_objects(not the main manager which is called objects)

Answer (score 8):

While you are calling:
`SmsToken.objects.all().delete()` you are calling the queryset's delete method.

But on `SmsTokent.objects.last().delete()` you are calling the instance's delete method.

After django 1.9 queryset `delete` method returns no of items deleted. [REF](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#delete)

> Changed in Django 1.9:
>   The return value describing the number of objects deleted was added.

But on instance `delete` method Django already knows only one row will be deleted.

Also note that querset's delete method and instance's delete method are different.

> The delete()`[on a querset]` method does a bulk delete and does not call any delete() methods on your models`[instance method]`. It does, however, emit the pre_delete and post_delete signals for all deleted objects (including cascaded deletions).

So you cannot rely on the response of the method to check if the delete worked fine or not. But in terms of python's philosophy "Ask for forgiveness than for permission". That means you can rely on exceptions to see if a delete has worked properly the way it should. Django's ORM will raise proper exceptions and do proper rollbacks in case of any failure.

So you can do this:

```
try:
    instance.delete()/querset.delete()
except Exception as e:
    # some code to notify failure / raise to propagate it
    # you can avoid this try..except if you want to propagate exceptions as well.
```

*Note: I am catching generic Exception because the only code in my try block is `delete`. If you wish to have some other code then you must catch specific exceptions only.*

Answer (score 6):

I assume that `SoftDeletableModel` comes from the [django-model-utils](https://github.com/carljm/django-model-utils/) package? If so, the [purpose](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models.html#softdeletablemodel) of that model is to mark instances with an `is_removed` field rather than actually deleting them. So it's to be expected that calling `delete()` on a model instance—which is what you get from `last()`—wouldn't actually delete anything.

`SoftDeletableModel` [provides](https://github.com/carljm/django-model-utils/blob/1e4bc27e3a56147ecc66c0b83a982c0290eac744/model_utils/models.py#L125) an `objects` attribute with a [manager](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/managers.html#softdeletablemanager) that limits its results to non-removed objects, and overrides `delete()` to mark objects as removed instead of actually deleting them.

The problem is that you've defined your own manager as `objects`, so the `SoftDeletableModel` manager isn't being used. Your custom manager is actually bulk deleting objects from the database, contrary to the goal of doing a soft delete. The way to resolve this is to have your custom manager inherit from [`SoftDeletableManagerMixin`](https://github.com/carljm/django-model-utils/blob/1e4bc27e3a56147ecc66c0b83a982c0290eac744/model_utils/managers.py#L257):

```
class NexchangeManager(SoftDeletableManagerMixin, models.Manager):
    # your custom code
```